# Optimizing rand query with join

Tags: mysql, sql, random

I have a rand query which runs very slow like almost every rand query. I researched all stackoverflow but cannot find any good solution for my query

```
SELECT u.id 
     , u.is_instagram_connected 
     , u.tokens 
     , u.username 
     , u.name 
     , u.photo 
     , u.bio 
     , u.voice 
     , u.mobile_update 
     , 1584450999 - l.time idleTime
  FROM mobile_login_list l
  JOIN users u
    ON l.username = u.username
  JOIN mobile_token_list t
    ON t.username = l.username 
 WHERE l.time > 1584393399
   AND l.username NOT IN ('enesdoo')
   AND u.username NOT IN (
                   SELECT blocked_username
                     FROM hided_mobile_users_from_shuffle
                    WHERE username = 'enesdoo'
                         )
   AND u.ban_status = 0
   AND u.perma_ban = 0
   AND u.mobile_online_status = 1
   AND u.lock_status = 0
 GROUP 
    BY l.username
 ORDER 
    BY RAND( )
 LIMIT 27
```

If i remove the `order by rand` line, this runs very very quick like 100 times faster.

How can i speed up this query?

**mobile_login_list has > 50k rows**

**users has > 1m rows**

Edit:

**Explain:**

[image]

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mobile_login_list` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `key` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `time` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ip` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `version` smallint(4) NOT NULL,
  `messaged` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `kontrol` (`username`,`key`),
  KEY `username` (`username`),
  KEY `time` (`time`),
  KEY `username_2` (`username`,`time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=3351637 ;
```

Comment: Please post explain plan

Comment: Run `EXPLAIN` and go from there.  A general answer to your question would be to just tune the entire query.

Comment: See my edit please

Comment: How many rows are there if you remove ORDER BY and LIMIT?

Comment: @SalmanA 4k rows

Comment: Note that in the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate.

Comment: @Strawberry thanks for the information, is this relevant with speed?

Comment: Speed is secondary to gibberish.

Comment: I'm with Strawberry here. First fix the defective query, then think about speed. Which `mobile_login_list.time` per user are you interested in? The greatest (`MAX)`? Least (`MIN`)? Whichever (`ANY_VALUE`)? And what's the use of `mobile_token_list` in that query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the lingo of random retrieval, this is called a *deal* operation (deal 27 different cards from a shuffled deck of 4k or so. The other random operation is called *roll*: it allows duplicates.)

You're using `SELECT mess-of-columns FROM mess-of-joins WHERE mess-of-criteria ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT small-number` to do shuffle and deal operation. That is a notorious performance antipattern. It causes some extra work for the server because it must order a fairly large result set then discard almost all of it (with the LIMIT).

A way to save some of the trouble is to defer the joins to the details. Shuffle only the ids. Then take the small number of results and fetch the details you need. Something like this.

```
          SELECT u.id    /* just the id values */
            FROM mobile_login_list l
            JOIN users u
              ON l.username = u.username
            JOIN mobile_token_list t
              ON t.username = l.username 
           WHERE l.time > 1584393399
             AND l.username NOT IN ('enesdoo')
             AND u.username NOT IN (
                             SELECT blocked_username
                               FROM hided_mobile_users_from_shuffle
                              WHERE username = 'enesdoo'
                                   )
             AND u.ban_status = 0
             AND u.perma_ban = 0
             AND u.mobile_online_status = 1
             AND u.lock_status = 0
           ORDER 
              BY RAND( )
           LIMIT 27
```

You can debug, run EXPLAIN and optimize this subquery by changing indexes and maybe tightening up your selection criteria. It's the one doing all the hard work of shuffling and dealing.

Then join that resultset to your detail tables to choose the data you need. This outer query only needs to process your 27 rows. Be sure to shuffle again.

```
SELECT u.id 
     , u.is_instagram_connected 
     , u.tokens 
     , u.username 
     , u.name 
     , u.photo 
     , u.bio 
     , u.voice 
     , u.mobile_update 
     , 1584450999 - l.time idleTime
  FROM mobile_login_list l
  JOIN users u
    ON l.username = u.username
  JOIN (
           /* the subquery from above */
       ) selected ON u.id = selected.id
  ORDER BY RAND()
```

Putting it all together, you get this big repetitive mess of a query. But it should be a little faster.

```
SELECT u.id 
   , u.is_instagram_connected 
   , u.tokens 
   , u.username 
   , u.name 
   , u.photo 
   , u.bio 
   , u.voice 
   , u.mobile_update 
   , 1584450999 - l.time idleTime
FROM mobile_login_list l
JOIN users u
  ON l.username = u.username
JOIN (
            SELECT u.id 
              FROM mobile_login_list l
              JOIN users u
                ON l.username = u.username
              JOIN mobile_token_list t
                ON t.username = l.username 
             WHERE l.time > 1584393399
               AND l.username NOT IN ('enesdoo')
               AND u.username NOT IN (
                               SELECT blocked_username
                                 FROM hided_mobile_users_from_shuffle
                                WHERE username = 'enesdoo'
                                     )
               AND u.ban_status = 0
               AND u.perma_ban = 0
               AND u.mobile_online_status = 1
               AND u.lock_status = 0
             ORDER 
                BY RAND( )
             LIMIT 27
     ) selected ON u.id = selected.id
 ORDER BY RAND()
```

A more performant way to deal records is this, if you do the dealing a lot.

1. Add a FLOAT column to the table you're dealing from, let's call it `deal`. Put an index on it.
2. Every few hours, or maybe overnight or even once a week, shuffle the table by running this query `UPDATE users SET deal = RAND();` It will take a while; it needs to change the `deal` value in every row.
3. When you need to deal, do `...WHERE deal >= RAND() * 0.9 ... ORDER BY deal LIMIT n`. The multiplication by 0.9 helps ensure you don't hit the end of the table by choosing a random number too close to 1.

This is equivalent, in cardshark terms, to shuffling the deck every few hours and then just [cutting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(cards)) it for every deal.   It's the way Wikipedia implements their "show a random article" feature.

Comment: I tried it but this runs with almost same speed with my first query :(

Comment: Please see my edit.  Also, the inner query, the one that selects records to shuffle, is quite complex. That, on top of the `RAND()`-based deal operation, probably makes for a long-running query. Can you simplify the selection of records?

Comment: But i don't understand why do we have to shuffle the table periodically?

Comment: What happens if i create ‘deal’ column for mobile_login_list table not for users? Because users has 1m rows which is too many for updating periodically but mobile_login_list has 50k rows

Comment: You put the `deal` column on the table you want to shuffle. I don't understand your application well enough to recommend which table that is for you.

Comment: Oh ok then, because i want to shuffle mobile_login_list. But why i have to update deal column periodically?

Comment: Again, you have not explained your application.  How random does your sample have to be? If you never update `deal` over time you will find yourself dealing the same rows in the same order to multiple different users.  It's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Can we see the EXPLAIN for this instead...?

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id 
              , u.is_instagram_connected 
              , u.tokens 
              , u.username 
              , u.name 
              , u.photo 
              , u.bio 
              , u.voice 
              , u.mobile_update 
              , 1584450999 - l.time idleTime
           FROM mobile_login_list l
           JOIN users u
             ON l.username = u.username
           JOIN mobile_token_list t
             ON t.username = l.username          
           LEFT
           JOIN hided_mobile_users_from_shuffle x         
             ON x.blocked_username = u.username
            AND x.username = 'enesdoo'         
          WHERE l.time > 1584393399
            AND l.username NOT IN ('enesdoo')
            AND x.blocked_username IS NULL
            AND u.ban_status = 0
            AND u.perma_ban = 0
            AND u.mobile_online_status = 1
            AND u.lock_status = 0
          ORDER 
             BY RAND( )
          LIMIT 27
```

Given my limited knowledge of query optimisation, I would simply define the table as follows, but maybe someone else can suggest further improvements:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mobile_login_list 
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,username varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
,`key` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
,time int NOT NULL
,ip int NOT NULL
,version smallint NOT NULL
,messaged int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
,KEY username_2 (username,time) -- or (time,username)
);
```

Note that `key` is a reserved word (and `time` is a 'keyword') rendering it a poor choice for a table/column identifier

Comment: I would ditch the l.time index (assuming it only indexes the time column) and instead construct one on either (time,username) or (username,time) - Try both, one at a time

Comment: Btw, i added my table to my question. Can you check that?